# Cursor Engine error '80004005'

Tags: asp-classic, cursor

There is a server in my company and its IP address has changeed yesterday !

And now there is a asp page could not work !

it shows:

```
Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80004005'

Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status.

/ccall/split.inc, line 23
```

here is the code:

```vbs
<%
mypage=request("whichpage")
If  mypage="" then
    mypage=1
end if
mypagesize=request("pagesize")
If  mypagesize="" then
    mypagesize=200
end if
mysql=request("SQLquery")
IF  mySQL="" THEN
   mySQL=SQL
END IF

myrs.cursorlocation=3
myrs.cachesize=5
myrs.Open sql,myconn,adOpenStatic

if not myrs.eof and not myrs.bof then

    myrs.movefirst
    myrs.pagesize=mypagesize
    maxpages=cint(myrs.pagecount)
    maxrecs=cint(myrs.pagesize)
    myrs.AbsolutePage=mypage
    howmanyrecs=0
    howmanyfields=myrs.fields.count -1

end if
%>
```

what make me confused is that it can work fine before ip changing.

**-- EDIT --**

```vbs
set myconn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
myconn.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("order.mdb") & ";"
```

Comment: You need to look at your connection string `myconn` and make sure the server setting has changed there.

Comment: Here is my connection string below: set myconn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
myconn.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("order.mdb") & ";"

Comment: Has the server [NATed](http://www.bing.com/search?q=nating+your+ip&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=nating+your+ip&sc=0-7&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=18643ce5ad6b484e915d579c867055a5) across properly?

Comment: Other page is work fine , just this one could not work! And I have a copy of the website on my PC , I make it run by iis perfectly , so why it could not work on the server

Comment: Try restarting IIS on the server see if that helps.

Comment: That error suggests you need a different cursor type.  I'm guessing here but try adOpenDynamic instead of adOpenStatic

Comment: I have made the problem solved . I repair the access db and it works fine then ,so why ?